# Firebase how to unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using `Ionic2` with `Angularfire2` to access `Firebase Authentication`.

I access the following `rxjs/Observable`:

**chats.ts**

```
  this.firelist = this.dataService.findChats();
  this.subscription = this.firelist.subscribe(chatItems => {
     ...
  });

  ngDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**dataService.ts**

```
findChats(): Observable<any[]> {
        this.firebaseDataService.findChats().forEach(firebaseItems => {
           ...
           observer.next(mergedItems);
        });
}
```

**firebaseDataService.ts**

```
findChats(): Observable<any[]> { // populates the firelist
    return this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
        }
    }).map(items => {
        const filtered = items.filter(
            item => (item.memberId1 === this.me.uid || item.memberId2 === this.me.uid)
        );
        return filtered;
    });
}
```

Also, in Firebase Authentication, I have the following Realtime Database Rules:

```
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
  }
```

**Problem**

This works perfectly while a user is logged in (i.e. `auth != null`), but a soon as a user logs out, and `auth == null`, I get the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /chat:
>   Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. Error:
>   permission_denied at /chat: Client doesn't have permission to access
>   the desired data.

**Question**

As you can see in the above code, I try to `unsubscribe` from the Firebase Authentication Service, but must be doing it incorrectly. If anyone can advise how I should `unsubscribe` in order to stop my app querying the Firebase database, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Why don't you do `this.firelist.unsubscribe()`

Comment: Hi Skeptor, thanks for the feedback. `this.firelist` is a `rxjs/Observable<any>`, and the api does not have an `unsubscribe` function. It does however, return a `Subscription` that does have one, so that's what I unsuccessfully try as shown above.  http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: I never unsubscribe so not sure about the syntax . But in my opinion you need to watch auth object status for every http call , instead of unsubscribing. I will provide a different way to write the same code and how i do in my app. ( I use aws, but they are almost same )

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the assistance.

Comment: What I meant is , if user is loggedout , any http call will fail and user will automatically redirected to login page . You need not manually unsubscribe.  I will add my code in couple of hours , am not at my desk right now .

Comment: What happens if a hacker logs in, and tries to access another users messages? That's where the Firebase Rules come in handy. You can only allow access to the messages that match the users `uid`. You can do something like: `      "chat": {
        "$key": {
         ".read": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid || true",         
         ".write": "data.child('memberId1').val() === auth.uid || data.child('memberId2').val() === auth.uid || true"          
        }
      },`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to the question, but my argument is we will never come to this issue if we do this other way.

P.S : I never used firebase , I use AWS so the firebase code might not be precise, we discuss about it .

Here is my version:

```
findChats(): Observable<any[]> { // populates the firelist
    return 
      this.authService.getCurrentUser()
        .flatMap(user => user === null ? 
          Observable.empty():        
          this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
             query: {
                orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
             }
           })
          .map(items => 
             return items.filter(
               item => (
                  item.memberId1 === this.me.uid || 
                  item.memberId2 === this.me.uid
               )
             ) 
          )
     );
}
```

Auth Service

```
public currentUser = new BehaviorSubject(null);

constructor(){

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
           // User is signed in.
           currentUser.next(user);
        } else {
         // No user is signed in.
           currentUser.next(null);
        }
    });

}
```

The code is very raw but I hope it conveys the idea. Here I am observing on the user authentication status and doing `flatMap` to fetch data. If user logs out, auth status change to null so in the UI data changes to empty list. Even if the user is not logged out , still he cannot see the data.

---

**UPDATE** :

Refactoring other answer:

```
findChats(){
   return Observable.merge(
       this.firebaseDataService
           .findChats()
           .flatMap(chats => Observable.from(chats)),
       this.localDataService
           .findChats()
           .flatMap(chats => Observable.from(chats))
   )
   .filter(chat => !!chat)
   .toArray()
   .map(chats => [
      ...chats.sort(
        (a, b) => 
           parseFloat(a.negativtimestamp) - parseFloat(b.negativtimestamp))
      ]
   );  
}
```

Except when you are caching response using `Subject` never use `subscribe` inside service.

Answer (score 0):

The `unsubscribe` is working correctly. The problem turns out that the following function I used, is causing it to subscribe twice for some reason:

```
findChats(): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.chatSubscription2 = this.firebaseDataService.findChats().subscribe(firebaseItems => {
            this.localDataService.findChats().then((localItems: any[]) => {
                let mergedItems: any[] = [];
                if (localItems && localItems != null && firebaseItems && firebaseItems != null) {
                    for (let i: number = 0; i < localItems.length; i++) {
                        if (localItems[i] === null) {
                            localItems.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    mergedItems = this.arrayUnique(firebaseItems.concat(localItems), true);
                } else if (firebaseItems && firebaseItems != null) {
                    mergedItems = firebaseItems;
                } else if (localItems && localItems != null) {
                    mergedItems = localItems;
                }
                mergedItems.sort((a, b) => {
                    return parseFloat(a.negativtimestamp) - parseFloat(b.negativtimestamp);
                });
                observer.next(mergedItems);
                this.checkChats(firebaseItems, localItems);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

For some reason the 3rd line above is called twice (even though the function is only called once). This is creating a second `subscription`, and the first `subscription` is never `unsubscribed`.

So it appears that the creation of the `Observable` is incorrect. I'm not sure what;s the correct way to create the `Observable` though.

Comment: I have posted a question on how to create the `Observable` so that there's only one subscription here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883886/observable-create-is-called-twice

Comment: You should not use `Observable.create` . Directly return `this.firebaseDataService` after doing some transformations using map .

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that because the list that makes use of the `Observable` is currently subscribing to it, i.e. it needs to update dynamically.

Comment: I will provide an update to my answer with refactored method